# No More default template showing while creating a new android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed android studio from old setup and updated it. Now while creating a new project there are no default templates other than these two.

Please help to get that back.

here is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see your templates in Android-Studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities. In your android-studio there are two activities.So you see two templates.For more templates you can add templates from old android-studio in this android-studio in above path.

Answer (score 1):

"Seems like you have updated the Android Studio but you have not yet updated the SDK, Would you please try updating the Android SDK with latest one and all its components.. This might solve the problem..."

Answer (score 0):

well I updated my studio, and while creating a new project I check marked "include c++ support"(New Feature), so because of this I was not able to see more default template.
So I just unchecked "include c++ support" and everything works good as before.
Thankyou